# I need to exclude Saturdays and Sundays from this program that shows dates of every 15 days

Tags: java, java-time

I'm trying to make a program that shows dates of every 15 days.

```
import java.time.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
;

public class test{
    public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m"; //ANSI Color code   //only for colored text. 
    public static final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m"; //ANSI Color code //only for colored text.
    public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m"; //ANSI Color code    //only for colored text.
    public static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m"; //ANSI Color code  //only for colored text.
    public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m"; //ANSI Color code   //Only for colored text.
    public static final String ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m"; //ANSI Color code //only for colored text.
    public static final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m"; //ANSI Color code   //only for colored text.
    public static final String ANSI_WHITE = "\u001B[37m"; //ANSI Color code  //only for colored text.



    public static void main(String[]args) {

        System.out.println(ANSI_YELLOW + "Bi-Weekly Calculator" + ANSI_RESET); //Introduction
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000); //Pause for 2 seconds
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        System.out.println(ANSI_YELLOW + "This calculator will only show dates for the next 12 months." + ANSI_RESET);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);//Pause for 2 seconds
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Date input from user
        System.out.print(ANSI_RED + "Enter Date : " + ANSI_RESET);
        String INPUT_DATE = scanner.next();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { //Line 37 to 41 for pausing the code for 2 seconds.
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


        LocalDate today = LocalDate.parse(INPUT_DATE);
        System.out.println("\n"+today);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(today.plusDays(15)+"\n"); //days added to input date.
        System.out.println(today.plusDays(30)+"\n");
        System.out.println(today.plusDays(45)+"\n");
        System.out.println(today.plusDays(60)+"\n");


    }
}
```

The program takes input from the user and adds 15, then 30, then 45, and so on. I need o remove Saturdays and Sundays from this program as I'm actually making this program for the every 15 day pay for someone.

I didn't find any good solution on google, and I'm kinda new with java. I'm using JDK 20.0.1 and IntelliJ IDEA as IDE.

Comment: `LocalDate` has a [`getDayOfWeek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#getDayOfWeek()) method, does that help?

Comment: So if payday falls in the weekend, the poor employee is not getting paid??

Comment: You need to specify what to do when the pay day falls on a weekend.  Does payday move to the following Monday or the previous Friday?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```java
package work.basil.example.time;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class FifteenDays
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ( "Africa/Tunis" );
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( z );

        int daysToJump = 15 , jumps = 5;  // Jump to 0, 15, 30, 45, 60 days out.
        Set < DayOfWeek > weekend = EnumSet.of ( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY );
        LocalDate localDate = today;
        for ( int jumpIndex = 0 ; jumpIndex < jumps ; jumpIndex++ )
        {
            int daysJumped = ( daysToJump * jumpIndex );
            localDate = localDate.plusDays ( daysJumped );
            if ( weekend.contains ( localDate.getDayOfWeek ( ) ) ) continue;
            System.out.println ( "jumpIndex: " + jumpIndex + " | daysJumped: " + daysJumped + " | localDate = " + localDate );
        }
    }
}
```

## Details

> LocalDate today =

To capture the current date, you need a time zone. If omitted, your JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. Understand that for any given moment,  **the date varies** around the globe by time zone; *tomorrow in Tokyo* Japan is simultaneously *yesterday in Toledo* Ohio.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

> shows dates of every 15 days

Define the count of days to jump, and how many times to jump.

```
int daysToJump = 15 , jumps = 5;  // Jump to 0, 15, 30, 45, 60 days out.
```

Define the first day from which we will jump.

```
LocalDate localDate = today;
```

Loop for the five iterations we want, adding 0, 15, 30, 45, 60. Add `daysToJump` on each.

```
for ( int jumpIndex = 0 ; jumpIndex < jumps ; jumpIndex++ ) { … }
```

```java
for ( int jumpIndex = 0 ; jumpIndex < jumps ; jumpIndex++ )
{
    int daysJumped = ( daysToJump * jumpIndex );
    localDate = localDate.plusDays ( daysJumped );
    System.out.println ( "jumpIndex: " + jumpIndex + " | daysToJump: " + daysToJump + " | localDate = " + localDate );
}
```

When run.

```
jumpIndex: 0 | daysJumped: 0 | localDate = 2023-05-25
jumpIndex: 1 | daysJumped: 15 | localDate = 2023-06-09
jumpIndex: 2 | daysJumped: 30 | localDate = 2023-07-09
jumpIndex: 3 | daysJumped: 45 | localDate = 2023-08-23
jumpIndex: 4 | daysJumped: 60 | localDate = 2023-10-22
```

You said:

> I need o remove Saturdays and Sundays

Yes, we can skip those dates that land on a weekend.

Define the weekend as a [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) of days of the week. Java comes with seven pre-defined [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) objects, one for each [day of the week](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html), Monday-Sunday.

```java
Set < DayOfWeek > weekend = EnumSet.of ( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY );
```

For each jump, add the days to jump, see if that date is on the weekend. If on weekend, ignore that date. If on a weekday, print. Add a test for day-of-week within the loop.

```java
for ( int jumpIndex = 0 ; jumpIndex < jumps ; jumpIndex++ )
{
    int daysJumped = ( daysToJump * jumpIndex );
    localDate = localDate.plusDays ( daysJumped );
    if ( weekend.contains ( localDate.getDayOfWeek ( ) ) ) continue;
    System.out.println ( "jumpIndex: " + jumpIndex + " | daysJumped: " + daysJumped + " | localDate = " + localDate );
}
```

When run:

```
jumpIndex: 0 | daysJumped: 0 | localDate = 2023-05-25
jumpIndex: 1 | daysJumped: 15 | localDate = 2023-06-09
jumpIndex: 3 | daysJumped: 45 | localDate = 2023-08-23
```

Comment: I don't think payday falling on a weekend means the employee doesn't get paid for that period.  The OP hasn't specified how to modify the pay date in those cases, but it's going to be either the previous Friday or the following Monday.

Comment: @JimGarrison I understand. That's why my Answer here serves *two* lessons. One lesson is about date-time classes. The other lesson is about being careful when stating software requirements. To quote: “shows dates of every 15 days” … “I need o remove Saturdays and Sundays”